# python immediately closing when I open program

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, calculator

I will admit i am just starting out python, but i seem to be having a problem. I created this calculator program and when i open it, the python window pops up for half a second than goes away. Does anybody have any idea why? Is it possibly a syntax error or something wrong with python? I am running windows 10 and the most recent version of python. all of my code is below, thanks.

```
def multiply():
    print("Choose two numbers to multiply by")
    A = int(input("Enter A: "))
    B = int(input("Enter B: "))
    return A * B

def divide():
    print("Choose two numbers to divide by")
    A = int(input("Enter A: "))
    B = int(input("Enter B: "))
    return A / B

def subtract():
    print("Choose two numbers to divide by")
    A = int(input("Enter A"))
    B = int(input("Enter B"))
    return A - B

def add():
    print("Choose two numbers to divide by")
    A = int(input("Enter A"))
    B = int(input("Enter B"))
    return A + B

def squareRoot():
    print("Choose what number to take the square root of")
    A = int(input("Enter A"))
    return A ** .5

def Square():
    print ("Choose what number to square")
    A = int(input("Enter A"))
    return A **

Print ("1: Addition")
Print ("2: Subtract")
Print ("3: Multiply")
Print ("4: Divide")
Print ("5: Square Root")
Print ("6: Square")
Print ("7: QUIT")

while True:
    Choice = int(input("Enter the corresponding number for calculation"))

    if Choice == 1:
        print ("Adding two numbers")
        print add()

    elif Choice == 2:
        print("Subtracting numbers")
        print subtract()

    elif Choice == 3:
        print("Multiplying numbers")
        print multiply()

    elif Choice == 4:
        print("Dividing numbers")
        print divide()

    elif Choice == 5:
        print("Taking the square root, your majesty")
        print squareRoot()

    elif Choice == 6:
        print("Squaring your god damned number")
        print squareRoot()

    elif Choice == 7:
        exit()

    else:
        Print("You didnt choose one of the options")
```

Comment: SyntaxError in `def Square():` `return A **`. You need an exponent. Probably `2` so `return A ** 2`

Answer (score 2):

Python starts up OK and begins running the script, but there is an error in `Square()` that raises an unhandled `SyntaxError` exception. The error causes the script to terminate and that closes the window. The return statement in `Square()` should be :

```
return A * A
```

not:

```
return A **
```

The next error is that you are calling `Print()` instead of `print()`. You are using Python 3, but there are other `print` *statements* which should actually be calls to the print *function*, i.e. `print()`, example line 48.

Also, there is a bug where option 6 calls `squareRoot()` instead of `Square()`.

The best way for you to find all of these errors is to execute your script from the command line of a windows terminal.

Comment: thanks for the fix, but the code still won't open properly.

Comment: Have you checked for other errors? If you run your script directly from a terminal you will be able to see the output without the window closing.

Comment: It should be `print()`, not `Print()`  in lines 35-41.

Comment: thank you all for the feedback, i have my program up and running much better

Comment: @ChrisHoward: glad to have helped. You can accept this answer if it solved your problem.